# Compact sets and topology proof

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, proof-writing, compactness

Consider the metric space $(\mathbb{R}^3, \|\cdot\|_2)$. Define $A=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3  ∶ x =y =z\}$.

(a) Decide whether or not the set A is compact. Prove your assertion.

(b) Determine interior, boundary and closure of A. Prove your assertion.

Really struggling with proofs and how to construct them in this context, any thoughts?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: What do you know about compact sets?

Comment: A good starting point would be to draw a picture and grasp what $A$ “looks like”

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this just the set of all scalar multiples of $(1,1,1)$ in $\mathbb R^3$?...

If so, it appears to not be  compact,  as it is unbounded. .. (heine-borel ).

It appears to contain all its limit points (a limit of a sequence of points on the line  would lie on the line ),  so appears closed.  So its closure is itself.

Its interior would appear empty: as it is just a line in $\mathbb R ^3$...  so contains no open sets in $\mathbb R ^3$...

As for its boundary,  that would I believe be it's closure ( itself)intersected with the closure of its complement($\mathbb R ^3$); hence the line itself. ..

Correct me if I am wrong. ..

Comment: Hi, I understand the general grasp of the topic, however, I don't understand the proof side, (I can't just say 'it is unbounded' I have to show it.)

Comment: @mblissett  hi.  How about if you are given a ball of radius $r$, centered at $0$, set $c=1,000r $...  Then (c,c,c) is outside the ball...